# sql server datetime where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Sorry for the lazy question. I want to know the SQL Server 2005 syntax for

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE myDateTimeField > "4am this morning"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE myDateTimeField > DATEADD(hh, 4, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

This:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 0)
```

...will return a DATETIME at midnight of the current day.  So the outer DATEADD adds four hours to that date at midnight to give you a DATETIME at 4 AM this morning.

Reference:

- [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myDateTimeField >
      DateAdd(hour, 4, DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

And just to be different, and arguably shorter/more readable than the other offerings:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE myDateTimeField > 
       cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) + ' 4AM' as datetime)
```

Of course, you might not really want to hard-code 4AM, but if you do, this way is nice and obvious in conveying your intent.

Comment: FYI: The fastest method of date truncation SQL Server is to use the DATEADD/DATEDIFF approach.